# How to merge multiple xml files with tinyxml

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I have multiple xml files that are structurally identical, looking like this:

- firstFile.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE/>
    <YEAR/>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

- secondFile.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CD>
  <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Red</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

My program uses TinyXML to load each of these files individually, without any problems. I am also able to perform all the other requirements of my program, using TinyXML
However, one of the goals of the program is to combine all such files, and then save it as a single file, that should look like this:

- combined.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE/>
    <YEAR/>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Red</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

A bit of googling revealed some discussions on "deep copy". But I couldn't get a relevant sample code. Hope some good hack around here, can share some.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230111/deep-copy-an-xml-via-tinyxml) could help.

Comment: In which computer programming language is your program written, sir?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am using C++

Comment: Then I'm curious as to why you tagged the question [tag:c].

Comment: Oh my ... most of your questions are tagged both C and C++. What's going on?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't mind. It is just my way of saying "Responses in either C or C++ are both equally welcome" :)

Comment: @LPs Yes, I had seen that post before I put up this question. But since it hasn't been upvoted by the post originator or anybody else, I wasn't sure if it works.